# Removing a concrete value from a set using function

Tags: python

(Newbie question) I want to write a Python program that removes a concrete item from a set if it is present in the set.

When the set is predefined, the code goes like this:

```
set = {1,2,3,4,4,5,6,10}
set.discard(4)
print(set)
```

What would be a way to write this, so that it applies to *any* set of values not known beforehand? I tried the following but it didn´t work. Is there a method along those lines that does?

```
def set(items):
    if i in items == 4:
        set.discard(4)
    else:
        print("The number 4 is not in the set.")
print(set({1,2,4,6}))
```

Comment: Also the `set` that you posted is invalid as it has two 4s (a set cannot have duplicates).

Comment: Thanks - I just realized the duplication. However, the first code works as intended when there is only one 4. I´m having difficulty with the second code. Even if I rename "set" (built-in function) to setA, it doesn´t execute.

Comment: @slider that is a totally valid `set` literal.

Comment: @arshajii `set.discard` works just fine.

Comment: @Madrid_datalady I'm not sure I understand your question. You can just use `.discard` directly on any given set. The following: `if i in items == 4:` is incorrect, to check membership in a set (and most containers) you just use `if 4 in items`, but you don't have to check first before using `.discard`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you, this is a useful explanation. I´m just getting started with Python, so still have a lot of confusion about how to express things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will discard the `4` in any set passed to the function:

```
def discard4(items):
    if 4 in items:
        items.discard(4)
        return "Discarded"
    else:
        return "The number 4 is not in the set." 
print(discard4({1,2,6}))    # will print "The number 4 is not in the set."
print(discard4({1,2,4,6}))  # will print "Discarded"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @Madrid_datalady Thank you on stackoverflow is upvoting + accepting. But you are welcome ;)

Comment: Yes, I did upvote your answer already and now I also accepted it! :)